# laravel Policy Too few arguments to function

Tags: laravel

It seems like I can't authorize users to update specific models. Authorizing all or none works but not for specific models.

Adding another argument for the 2nd Model doens't seem to work:

```
Too few arguments to function App\Policies\ProjectPolicy::update(), 1 passed
```

This is the Policy (even though its obviously not done yet):

```
public function update(User $user, Project $project)
{
    dd($project)
}
```

This is the authorization in the Project Controller:

```
if ( !$currentUser->can( 'update', Project::find($id) ) )
{

}
```

Comment: you call two parameter check your route if pass two or one parameter

Comment: @AlexanderVillalobos I'm calling the function in the controller as shown above and according to all documentation and examples I've seen, that's the correct syntax.

Comment: you cant put route?

Comment: This is the route
`Route::resources([
     'projects'      => 'ProjectController',
    ]);`

Comment: you need define one route for you route and put two parameter try delete one parameter and view you function work

Comment: @AlexanderVillalobos I think you've missunderstood, this has nothing to do with views or routes, it has to do with Policies. I did just solve it on my own though but thanks for your help anyway. :)

Answer (score 1):

Seems like `$this->authorize('update', Project::find($id))` was the correct syntax, however, I also had some other conflicting issues that I didn't notice.

Answer (score 0):

This [Too few arguments][1]

[1]: https://webstoked.com/set-up-controller-methods-policies-laravel/ gave me some deep insight.
Instead of:

```
public function update(Post $post, $id){
$this->authorize('update', $post);
$data = $this->validateRequest();
if (Post::where('id', $id)->exists()) {...
```

Use...

```
public function update(Post $post){
$this->authorize('update', $post);
$data = $this->validateRequest();
if ($post->id) {...
```